# jQuery AJAX post returns 403 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following script for AJAX to do login, but with some passwords that contain characters like "!@#" it will return 403 error and will not submit to the PHP.

```
$(document).ready(function () { // When the document is ready
    $('#login').click(function (e) { // We attach the event onchange to the select element

        e.preventDefault();

        var form_info = "";
        $('#login_form *').filter(':input').each(function(){
            if(this.value !== ""){
                form_info += this.name;
                form_info += "=";
                form_info += encodeURIComponent(this.value);
                form_info += "&";
            }
        });
        form_info += "function_name=login";

        var form = $('#login_form').serialize() + "&function_name=login";

        $.ajax({
            url: "function_ajax.php", // path to you php file 
            type: "post", // We want a POST request
            dataType: 'html',
            data: form_info,
            statusCode:
                    {
                        404: function () {
                            alert('Could not contact server.');
                        },
                        500: function () {
                            alert('A server-side error has occurred.');
                        }
                    },
            error: function ()
            {

                alert('A problem has occurred.');
            },
            beforeSend: function ()
            {
                alert(form_info); 
                alert(form); 
            },
            complete: function ()
            {
            },
            success: function (data) { // The function to execute if the request is a -success-, 

                if(data === "1"){
                    if (document.referrer !== "") {
                        window.location.href = document.referrer;
                    }
                    else{
                        window.location.href = "some_domain"
                    }
                }
                else if (data === "2")
                {
                    alert("invalid");
                }
                else { 
                    alert("empty");
                }
            } 
        });
    });

});
```

You will find that I'm trying both ways to encode each element and the serialize just to check if I'm getting the same result, and I'm getting the same result, but still, it's getting this error.

If I try to encode the whole serialize, then I will not get the error but in PHP, the $_POST array will have the first key as the data I'm sending with no value.

```
encodeURIComponent($('#login_form').serialize()) + "function_name=login"
```

then the $_POST will be like

```
array(
[email=email@gmail.com&password=pass123!@#&function_name=login]=>
)
```

which will not be useful for me.

Comment: contentType `html`? Try `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` or just remove it since that it's default anyway.

Comment: that was just to test, forgot to remove it, I tried what you proposed, not working

Comment: Response code is from server, but you did not provide any server related code, so we can't help you